# What are the advantages of using an autoencoder to build a set of filters versus a prebuilt set of gabor filters in relation to CNNs?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, neural-network

I'm working on a convolutional neural network and I've found various methods of building filters to convolve the image with. What are the advantages and disadvantages of each?

Answer (score 5):

Using autoencoders may in some cases improve performance, yield biologically plausible filters, and more importantly, give you a model based on your data instead of predefined filters. Autoencoders will give you filters that may fit your data better, in general. The only downside is of course the additional computation time. However, in many cases it doesn't hinder you from learning online.

For more evaluations you might have a look at:
http://www.idsia.ch/~masci/papers/2011_icann.pdf

Comment: Is it possible to just randomly generate filters and get decent results? As long as we learn to adjust the weights will the filters converge?

Comment: I think it's fine. The linked paper compares their results with the autoencoders to random initialization, though. They conclude that the pretraining gives slightly better results so it might be worth checking out.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I might start off with random weights and work up to a stacked autoencoder, I'm still grasping the details of a CNN.  How is the locally connected input chosen? It seems I define "local" (as in how many corresponding neurons to connect to). I'm using this as my main source: http://ufldl.stanford.edu/tutorial/supervised/FeatureExtractionUsingConvolution/